# Jquery conflict in VF Page

Tags: visualforce, jquery, datatable

I am using custom component, that component controller called jquery-1.11.3.min.js. after that i called jquery-1.11.1.min.js for datatables. If i removed jquery-1.11.1.min.js file datatables not working properly. If i use component at the end of the document datatable not displaying the paginations. All records displaying in in the same page. here is the my code.

```
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Jquery_sumo_select, '/sumoselect.css')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Jquery_sumo_select, '/jquery.sumoselect.min.js')}" /> 

<script>
    j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

    j$.extend( j$.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
        "point-numeric-pre": function ( a ) {
            var vals = a.match(/([0-9]+[\.]+[0-9]+([\.]+[0-9]+)?)/g);
            var res = [0, 0, 0];

            if (vals) {
                vals = vals[0].split('.');
                for (var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
                    res[i] = parseInt(vals[i]);
                }
            }    
            return 1000000*res[0] + 1000*res[1] + res[2];
        },

        "point-numeric-asc": function ( a, b ) {
            return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
        },

        "point-numeric-desc": function ( a, b ) {
            return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
        }
    });

    j$(document).ready( function () {
        var aa = j$('[id$="resultTable"]').DataTable({
            columnDefs: [
              { type: 'point-numeric', targets: 3 }
            ],
            order: [[ 3, "asc" ]]
        });
         var contactTable = j$('[id$="approvalTable"]').DataTable({
          "bSort": false,
           columnDefs: [
              { type: 'point-numeric', targets: 3 }
            ]
        });
    });
```

"Uncaught TypeError, Cannot read property oSort of undefined." error message showing.

Answer (score 3):

You can isolate your DataTables JavaScript code to its specific version of jQuery by using this pattern:

```
<script src="... path to jquery-1.11.1 ..."></script>
<script>
(function(j$) {
    ... your Datatables code goes here ...
})(jQuery.noConflict());
</script>
```

Note that the included jQuery reference and the DataTables `script` tags need to be right next to each other.

This works because including jQuery in the page changes the definition of `$` and invoking `jQuery.noConflict()` restores the previous value and also returns the current value which in this case is passed into the execution of an anonymous function where you code can use it.

Comment: Hi Keith, i kept the code inside function like what you said. but no luck. same error message it's showing and pagination not working.

Comment: @VijayKumar Looks like you'll have to use your browser's debugging tools then; you can set breakpoints and examine data and so hopefully figure out what/why this is broken.